# How does "[attribute]_changed?" work with CarrierWave mount_uploader :[attribute]?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I have got CarrierWave uploader in my model.

```
before_validation :parse_template_file, if: :template_file_changed?
mount_uploader :template_file
```

My code above doesn't work throwing  `NoMethodError template_file_changed?`.

How can I check the file was changed before saving the record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`some_attr_changed?` is an instance method so you need to call it on an instance of your model.

So, instead of this...

```
before_validation :parse_template_file, if: :template_file_changed?
```

Try something like this...

```
before_validation :parse_template_file, if: :file_changed?

private

def file_changed?
  self.template_file_changed?  # self can be implied
end
```